# What is the best way to display HTML in Flex?

Tags: html, apache-flex, actionscript, text

I have HTML that includes symbols such as the Trademark "TM" as superscript (™). In normal HTML, I would use `"&trade;"` or `&#153;` to display the Trademark TM. However, I can find no way to import HTML like this into Flex and have it displayed correctly. I am having similar issues with the `<li>` tag.

My HTML:

```
<p>This information is intellectual property of My Company&#153;.</p>

<p>Available features:</p>

<li>Feature 1</li>
<li>Feature 2</li>
<li>Feature 3</li>
<li>Feature 4</li>

<p>COPYRIGHT INFORMATION:</p>

<p>Copyright &#169; 2008, My Company. All rights reserved.</p>
```

The only way that I've gotten this to work is by copying and pasting the content directly into Flex:

```
<mx:Text width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:htmlText>
        <![CDATA[
This information is intellectual property of My Company™. 

Available features:

•   Feature 1
•   Feature 2
•   Feature 3
•   Feature 4

COPYRIGHT INFORMATION:

Copyright © 2008, My Company. All rights reserved. 
        ]]>
    </mx:htmlText>
</mx:Text>
```

I want to use an external HTML file that I can import into my Flex App at run time, so that I don't have to recompile the app for a simple content change.

I've heard of too many issues with the iFrame option, so I want to avoid that, if possible.

Does anyone have any other good suggestions for dealing with this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is a tricky one.  I just finished a project where we used this open-source library to display HTML:  http://code.google.com/p/flex-htmlfilter

It handles lists, tables, etc, and is pretty easy to work with.  But, I don't think it supports the trademark symbol.  It does support some of the others, though.

I'm using it to pull content from a CMS and display in my flash movie.  It has worked great, and allows me all the flash styling flexibility I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a good solution for all problems, but if you want to use a RichText control you can load FlowText in to it which allows you to use more HTML, including superscript and other glyphs, like the ones you want to use.

[How to use superscripting in flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601507/how-to-use-superscripting-in-flex/13164076#13164076)